# Why does Burt say these words in "Go (1999)" movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, go

In *Go (1999)*, Burt, Adam & Zack have a conversation in car near the mall.

> Burt: Now this chick, Ronna, you think she can score?
>
> Adam: Maybe.
>
> Zack: Yeah, definitely.
>
> Burt: **Then that's all we need. It's all connected. Circle of life.**

I know the meaning of this sentence, but why does Burt say these words?

Comment: -1 [I'm not sure if these type of qestions are on-topic](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/what-type-of-dialogue-related-questions-are-allowed-here)

Comment: Asking why a character said something or what they mean is 100% on topic. Do not down vote someone if you aren't even sure if its off topic or not.

Answer (score 2):

"The Circle of Life" means that as one thing ends (or dies), another thing will begin (or be born). The phrase was made popular by the song of the same name in The Lion King (1994).

Adam and Zack were busted for drug possession. They have been coerced into trying to entrap their dealer, presumably as part of a plea bargain (their prison sentence will be reduced if they aid the entrapment).

Thus, if Ronna can score some drugs, she will be arrested. She will suffer, and they will benefit. Circle of Life.